# Why is MongoDB's local database almost completely in memory?

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

I have a replicated mongodb setup and I am seeing a lot of page faults. So I started to investigate and found out (through `vmmap`) that almost the entire `local` database is in memory (that is, part of the working set). The only collection of significance there is of course the `oplog.rs` which is used for replication. Looking at the queries being run, the ones on the oplog are for data that is a lot closer to the tail than to the head of the oplog. So why is the entire thing still in memory? Surely it should be swapped out due to the large amount of faults.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Am I reading the `vmmap` information incorrectly? Or is something actually going wrong?

[image: VMMap screenshot]

*Note that this is a testing setup and there are some other `mongod` instances running on this hardware, therefore the total amount of memory used here does not sum up to the total in the machine. Overall, the memory usage is ~100% though.*

Comment: your oplog.rs collection is not static - as you perform writes more documents are being written to it.  The reason "old" stuff isn't being swapped out is because it's being overwritten by new stuff instead.  What does db.printReplicationInfo() show?

Comment: `db.printReplicationInfo()` is broken. There is an issue for it, but I can't find it at the moment (it shows two dates in 1970, due to conversion of timestamp to milliseconds I believe). I have checked manually a while ago though (because I wanted to know how long my secondary could stay down without becoming stale) and it is about a day. The database is very active though and I am seeing around 50K pagefaults per second when it is most active. So I would expect day-old documents to be swapped out.

Comment: Maybe there is a current operation against the oplog? Perhaps someone ran a query against it that is scanning big parts of the collection. Check db.currentOp() on local.

Answer (score 4):

Mongo delegates page management to the kernel - since it uses mapped files, it just relies on the kernel to decide what to page out. Your `local` database is being touched every time you do a write, or receive a read from another. The oplog is a capped collection, so it's going to be constantly modifying a fixed space in the data files (and thus, a fixed space in RAM), which should keep it touched and not very high on the priority list for being paged out.

As to your high number of page faults, is it possible that those are simple cache warming? Mongo isn't going to load its working set into memory when it's freshly started, so it'll take a bit of querying for things to warm up and get stuff off of disk and into memory.

Don't forget to account for caches and buffers - your memory usage might be reading at 100%, but the kernel is going to expire caches and buffers before it pages out other things, so it might be that while your system is reporting close to 100% usage, a significant chunk of that is caches and buffers that'll be flushed as needed, meaning that mongo's working set never has to be paged out at all.

You might be able to test this by running a program designed to eat more and more memory ([like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/how-to-test-swap-partition)) and see how mongo behaves once your system is actually hitting swap.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for your answer. I understand 'local' is being touched on every write and that would keep the tail of it in memory. My concern is the fact that the entire thing appears to be in memory. The database has been running for quite some time at the moment of the screenshot (weeks under heavy load), so I am relatively certain that the documents are in fact in RAM (also, the working set of 11GB in the screenshot is almost entirely made up of mapped files representing collections). So I am still curious why the head of the oplog is apparently not paged out.